# Having layers on top of hillshade in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, layers, hillshade

I am currently trying to import some OSM data into QGIS and styling it a bit. For what I want to do, it's necessary to have a hillshade and some contour lines, which i both managed to create following some tutorials, but when I try to draw polygons on top of the hillshade I get what's in picture #1 (the shading does not apply do the polygon), while my goal is something along the lines of what's shown in picture #2.

[image: What I have (shading is not applied to the polygon)]

[image: What I'd like to get]

Answer (score 7):

Lowering the opacity of your fill colour might be sufficient.

[image]

[image]

---

Otherwise, you could try changing the layer blending mode to `Overlay`.

[image]

[image]

With this method, you might need to experiment with the colour to get it looking how you want.